# How to use PReLU in conv2d layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use PReLU activation function in the below code line, kindly let me know how to do it.

```
x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', strides= (2,2), "activation = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid", name='layer1')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a layer, like this:

```
x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', strides= (2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.PReLU()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
```

As dscribed in the [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/prelu/)

Comment: I tried but getting this error "ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor." @nicolas-gervais